# Write Device Token to custom class in Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, devicetoken

After a user registers their device, I am trying to write the users device token to a custom class column as well as in the Installation class - is there an easy way to do this or pull the device token as a variable everytime a user submits data to Parse?

Code in appdelegate.swift

```
        func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    let installation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
    installation.addUniqueObject("Status", forKey: "channels")
    installation.setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)
    installation.saveInBackground()
}
```

Code in submitcontroller.swift

```
            var query :PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "submission")
    var object_submission = PFObject(className: "submission")
    object_submission.setObject(appdelegate.deviceToken, forKey: "deviceToken")
```

Comment: Have you considered using cloud code?

Comment: I'm using cloud code to send the push notification but I would like to only send it when the users status has changed so I'm trying to target a specific user by having their ID match in the Installation class and my custom class

Comment: Instead of storing the device token twice, why not just add a Pointer to the User in the Installation class?

Comment: I'm not using a unique user name for users so the only way to match is via deviceToken or phone number. This is my cloud code to send the push:

        Parse.Cloud.afterSave("submission", function(request) {
 var commentText = request.object.get('status');

 var firstquery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
 firstquery.equalTo('Phone');

 var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.submission);
 pushQuery.matchesQuery('Phone', firstquery);